# Dynamically populate Modal popup

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I was trying to resolve an issue with staying on the current page in a jQuery data table. When "Edit" link in a row was clicked, it would open a modal pop up and populate the controls. This required a postback that set the page to page 1 again. Spent entire morning looking for solutions and none worked.

So I decided to populate the modal using ajax; solved my paging issue but somehow the controls in modal are not populated.

This is what I have tried:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog fade in ui-draggable">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header ui-draggable-handle">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="spnEditHeader"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        ....
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ddlArea">Area</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server"
                                ID="ddlArea"
                                ClientIDMode="Static"
                                CssClass="form-control"
                                DataTextField="AreaName"
                                DataValueField="AreaID"
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Area" Value="-1" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ddlDistrict">District</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server"
                                ID="ddlDistrict"
                                Enabled="false"
                                ClientIDMode="Static"
                                CssClass="form-control"
                                DataTextField="DistrictName"
                                DataValueField="DistrictID"
                                AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select District" Value="-1" />
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

(part of data table with edit link):

```
tblMPOO = $('#tblMPOO').DataTable({
    jQueryUI: true,
    data: [],
    dom: 'lfrtip',
    stateSave: true,
    stateDuration: 60 * 10,
    order: [[0, "asc"], [1, "asc"], [2, "asc"]],
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": "MPOOID"
        }, { ...
        }, {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    var cellContent = '';
                    cellContent =
                        "<a href='javascript:' onclick=\"showEdit('" + row.MPOOID + "'); \">Edit</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp;" +
                        "<a href='javascript:' onclick=\"deleteCourse('" + row.MPOOID + "', '" + row.DistrictID + "'); \">Delete</a>";
                    return cellContent;
            }
        ],
        "pageLength": 15,
        processing: true
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#editModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show: false
    }).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {debugger
        //var mpooID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('MPOOID');
        var mpooID = $('#hfMPOOID').val();
        //make ajax call to populate items
        populateMPOOEdit(mpooID);
    });

    $(".modal-dialog").draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header"
    });
});

function showEdit(MPOOID) {debugger
    $('#hfMPOOID').val(MPOOID);
    showEditModal();
}

function showEditModal() {
    some other stuff here ...

    $('#editModal').modal('show');
}

function populateMPOOEdit(mpooID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("services/mpoo.asmx/GetMPOOListByMPOOID") %>',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "MPOOID": mpooID }),
    }).done(function (result) {
        jResult = JSON.parse(result.d);
        $.each(jResult, function (val, txt) {debugger
            $('#tbMPOOName').val = txt.MPOOName;
           // $('#tbMgrFN').val = txt.ManagerFirstName; <--- This is wrong, corrected below
            $('#tbMgrFN').val(txt.ManagerFirstName); 
            $('#tbMgrLN').val(txt.ManagerLastName);
            $('#tbPhone').val(txt.Phone);
            $('#tbEmail').val(txt.Email);
            var AreaID = txt.AreaID;
            var DistrictID = txt.DistrictID;
            $("#ddlArea")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            $("#ddlDistrict")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            $("#ddlArea").val(AreaID);
            $("#ddlArea").change(); <-- added this to force its onchange event to fire
            $("#ddlDistrict").val(DistrictID); <-- This still doesn't work
        });
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errMsg = textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '... Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ",  ResponseText: " + jqXHR.responseText;
    });
}
```

another question, in the same context: I use ajax to populate one drop down list based on selection change in another (both drop downs are in aforementioned modal). I use onchange() of the first DDL to populate second DDL. Works fine.

Assuming this issue is resolved and controls are populated, would setting first drop down's value in js function trigger its onchange event?

**Update**

I made some of the changes that fixed the issue with controls values not populating; marked them in updated code. In "populateMPOOEdit()" I also forced the onchange() event of Area drop down list to fire. However, on next line when I set the District drop down's selected value, it doesn't work (some timing issue?)

Comment: I am almost ashamed to say what the error was! In "populateMPOOEdit" function I was assigning values of controls as bla.val = somehing instead of bla.val(something). However, I am still having the issue that when I set Area drop down's value, it does not trigger an onchange() event to populate Districts drop down.

Comment: Got the second issue to work (partially). calling $('#ddlArea').change() forces drop down's on change event to fire. However, it seems at this point District drop down is not completely populated since $('#ddlDistrict').val(DistrictID) has no effect. Not sure how to set the selected value for second drop down. I edited the question and updated it with the fixes I have so far iplemented.

Answer (score 0):

answer to this question is in another post where I asked specifically for how to handle two lined drop down lists using ajax.
[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827990/drop-down-list-not-populating-in-modal-dialog-when-item-in-first-drop-down-is-ch)